# Incorrect zoom level for horizontal polyline in a MKMapView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm using a `MKMapView` to display a polyline between two coordinates.
In order to ensure that the entire polyline is visible in the map view, I'm using its `setVisibleMapRect(_:edgePadding:animated:)` method.

This works fine when the polyline I'm drawing is from north to south (or vice-versa):

[image]

However, with an east to west (or vice versa) polyline rendered, not all of it is visible, and the user must zoom out in order for it to be fully visible:

[image]
[image]

In this test project, the map view is added to a view controller and has its constraints set so that it fills the entirety of its superview.

The code I'm using to generate the above example is as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    var verticalLine = [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.711043, -74.008243), CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.988465, -73.807804)]
    var horizontalLine = [CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.798569, -74.269200), CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.804152, -73.771390)]

    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &horizontalLine, count: 2)
    mapView.addOverlay(polyline, level: .AboveRoads)

    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(polyline.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0), animated: false)

}
```

How can I ensure that the entire line is visible when either a vertical or horizontal polyline is rendered? The above behaviour is exhibited in both iOS 8.2 and iOS 9.1.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I got the same problem.

Comment: @ChrisVanBuskirk Still working on it, but I'll keep this post updated should I find an answer.

Comment: Try my answer.  It fixed my problem, which was the same horizontal polyline issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing your zooming using dispatch_async

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self zoomInOnRoute];
});
```

Comment: Wow, I did not expect something like that to fix it – especially considering how I was not doing anything multithreaded.